# Events of own control in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView on the form, then I added a checkBox programically.

I added it to dataGridView.Controls list.  Now I would like to run the method  c_CheckedChanged every time  when event of changing the checkbox is raised. 
I did it in as in the code below, but it does nothing when I change the status of the checkBox.

How can add methods to the events of elements from  dataGridView.Controls list?

I know I can use DataGridViewCheckBoxCell instead of standard checkBox, but it is not the solution I am looking for. I am trying to learn how to create events of custom controls in Controls.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cb=new CheckBox();
        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(cb);

        (dataGridView1.Controls[0] as CheckBox).CheckedChanged += c_CheckedChanged;
    }
    private void c_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a=1;
    }
}
```

I used the code var a=1; to put here breakpoint and check if the method is done.
But it is not.

Could you help, please?
Regards,
Kris

Comment: When I ran your code as is, I got an exception on the line `(dataGridView1.Controls[0] ...`. I changed it to `(dataGridView1.Controls[2] ...` and it worked as it should with the event firing

Comment: _”I am trying to learn how to create events of custom controls in Controls.”_ … ? … “where” is your “custom” control? Is the `CheckBox` a control you created?

Comment: JayV, your answer solves my problem - there were two scroll bars added automatically to Controls, so my checkBox is third on the list. Thanks !

Comment: @kris The thing is, you do not have to use `Controls` of DataGridView. Just add that handler directly to the checkbox: `cb.CheckedChanged += c_CheckedChanged;`. Than it does not matter at which index it is inside DataGridView. Using `Controls` and some index is dangerous, because you do not know what is inside and if it will be the same in the next version/different setup of DGW... So _in general_, index which works now may not work in the future.